# Can pd.eval() return Nan or None, and not only True/False values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, eval

I have a pandas dataframe with missing values, for example :

```
  My_var1   My_var2   My_var3   My_var4
0     No         W6        No       Nan
1     No         W6        No       Nan  
2     No         W6        No       Yes
3     No         W6        No        No
4     No         W6        Yes       No
```

I also have a series of data filter stored in str format, for example :

```
"(My_var4 == 'Yes')"
```

I use this filter with eval() to get a boolean series :

```
my_data.eval(my_filter)
```

But for Nan values, the eval function returns False instead of Nan, but I'd like it to return Nan...

How can I apply str filters to my pd dataframe, and get True, False and Nan (or None) values returned ?

Answer (score 1):

`eval` has a very limited set of [supported syntax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#supported-syntax) so generally you can't do more complicated logical expressions.

To get exactly the behavior you describe is impossible. That is, you won't get `eval` to return an Object Series with `True/False/NaN`. I think the closest you can get is a float column with `1/0/NaN`. This requires some mental gymnastics to identify `NaN` by its property that  `X != X` is True and that np.arcsin(X) for X > 1 does return `NaN`

```
s = "(My_var4 == 'Yes') * arcsin((My_var4 != My_var4) + sin(1))"
df.eval(s)

0    NaN
1    NaN
2    1.0
3    0.0
4    0.0
Name: My_var4, dtype: float64
```